# Can I send periodic progress value as response from a Servlet to Client for a Single Request?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am having the following requirement .. 
A servlet is there who scans database with huge dataset and fetch all metadata information, if the database is big it takes 2+ minutes to scan ,
Instead of only showing loading i want to show the actual progress in % in client machine by sending a calculated value as response periodically .. But the main roadblock to this is only single response is possible from servlet to client , How  i can achieve this ??

Comment: You could use WebSocket for this.

Comment: As an alternative to WebSocket as suggested by @meskobalazs, you could make another servlet which would share some state (progression percentage) with your existing one and call this other one periodically (with ajax requests).

Comment: @dotvav  Great .. thanks man .. I got ur Idea .. I can periodically update the progress status to a session variable and can fetch using a another servlet and a ajax call while the main request will execute without interruption !! thanks man ..